# composite c1 - how to overwrite @header-image-url from a page or template

Tags: header, composite

I just installed Compsite C1 with Razor enabled. Now I am trying to find out how to easily change the Header-Image on different pages.

As far as I have found out, it is done via this variable "@header-image-url". But I do not know much about Razor, CSS and stuff. Just starting to learn. Could anyone give me a help on how to set a different URL to this variable from a template as well as from a page.

I think it should be put into the HEAD-Section of a page or template. But i do not know the correct syntax.

Thanks for your help in advance!